# ¿Cómo puedo enviar datos desde Laravel PHP a Angular para mostrarlos?

Tags: php, python, laravel

Tengo el resultado de un script de Python que se ejecuta con un argumento enviado desde Angular, y ahora la salida de dicho script la quiero enviar de nuevo a Angular para mostrar dicha información.

Función que ejecuta el script y recoge la salida:

```
public function procesar_texto($texto) {
    
    $argumento = '"'.$texto.'"';
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
    $cmd = "python ".storage_path('ejecutables\resumenAutomatico.py'.' '.$argumento);
    $salida = shell_exec($cmd);
    error_log($salida);
    return $salida;
}
```

La salida es de tipo string.

Esta es la ruta que uso para enviar el argumento a la función que ejecuta el script en Laravel.

```
Route::post('/resumen/insertar/{texto}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PictogramasController@procesar_texto');
```

Comment: No no falla simplemente que no sé la manera de enviar el return a Angular.

Comment: Pero tendría que crear una ruta con un método GET que recoja el json o como se haría?

Comment: Al menos puedes explicar mejor la idea del llamado ajax??

Comment: Vale lo investigaré gracias por la idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Prueba retornándolo como JSON

```
   public function procesar_texto($texto) {

    $argumento = '"'.$texto.'"';
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
    $cmd = "python ".storage_path('ejecutables\resumenAutomatico.py'.' '.$argumento);
    $salida = shell_exec($cmd);
    error_log($salida);
    return response()->json($salida);
}
```